# C++ STL: std::find with std::map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl, iterator

Python allows you to write `if e in arr: ...` *and* `if key in dict: ...` which is handy.

Can we do something similar with the latter using `std::find()` and `std::map` ? That will allow me to uniformly handle `std::array` and `std::map` with a single generic function, without explicitly switching to `std::map::find()`.

But if overloading `operator==()` is the only way, I'd rather give up this idea...

### Update: note I already have a sort of solution

By "overloading `operator==()`" I meant something like this:

```
template<typename K>
struct KF {
    K&& k;

    template <typename V>
    friend bool operator==(const typename std::pair<const K, V>& pair, const KF<K>& o) {
        return pair.first == o.k;
    }

};

template <typename K>
KF<K> keyFinder(K&& k) { return KF<K>{ std::forward<K>(k) }; }

int main() {
    std::set<int> s{ 1, 2, };
    cout << (std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 1) == s.end()) << endl; // => 0
    cout << (std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 3) == s.end()) << endl; // => 1

    std::map<int, int> m{ {1,10}, {2,20}, };
    cout << (std::find(m.begin(), m.end(), keyFinder(1)) == m.end()) << endl; // => 0
    cout << (std::find(m.begin(), m.end(), keyFinder(3)) == m.end()) << endl; // => 1
}
```

- http://ideone.com/7ULUe9

Things get more complicated when we deal with non-scalar `K` in an universal way (perfect forwarding *etc.* ?)

Answer (score 6):

...why not write your own utility function?

```
template <typename TContainer, typename TValue>
bool contains(const TContainer& c, const TValue& x);
```

You can use *overloading* to match the containers:

```
template <typename TValue, std::size_t N>
bool contains(const std::array<TValue, N>& c, const TValue& x)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(c), std::end(c), x) != std::end(c);
}

template <typename TValue, typename... Ts>
bool contains(const std::map<Ts...>& c, const TValue& x)
{
    return c.find(x) != std::end(c);
}
```

Usage:

```
std::array<int, 2> a{1,2};
std::map<int, int> b{{1,2},{3,4}};

assert(contains(a, 1));
assert(!contains(a, 42));
assert(contains(b, 1));
assert(!contains(b, 42));
```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XIn4sPt7cfDF52V8)

---

If you want to support additional containers in the future, it's a good idea to use *SFINAE* to check whether or not a particular expression is valid. This approach works well because it doesn't care about the type of the container, it only cares about what operations can be performed on it.

The [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) would likely make it very easy to check member availability through SFINAE *(and its implementation is C++11 compatible)*.

I also wrote an article about *checking expression validity* in-situ with C++17, which could be an interesting read. Despite its title, it covers C++11, C++14 and C++17 techniques to check expression validity:

[**"checking expression validity in-place with C++17"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/checking_expression_validity_in_place.html)

Comment: This is what I meant by "explicitly switching to `std::map::find()`" ... what if I want to support `unorderd_map`, `multimap`, and third party libraries like `spp::sparse_hash_map` as well?  Check if there's `M::find` with SFINAE?

Comment: @nodakai: that could work - the [**detection idiom**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) would likely make it very easy to check member availability through SFINAE (and its implementation is C++11 compatible).

Comment: @nodakai: I added additional information about the SFINAE approach to my answer - let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your explicit question - no, `std::find` won't be able to work uniformly for `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` and `std::array`/`std::vector` as the former is a collection of key/value pairs and the latter is collection of values...

You may want to use `std::find_if` instead as it gives you a little bit more flexibility on defining equality condition e.g. like this (c++1z approach):

```
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct is_pair: std::false_type { };

template <class K, class V>
struct is_pair<std::pair<K,V>>: std::true_type { };

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> m {{"abc", 1}, {"cde", 2}, {"efg", 3}};
    std::array<int, 5> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    auto lambda = [](auto it) {
        if constexpr (is_pair<decltype(it)>::value) {
            return it.second == 3;
        } else {
            return it == 3;
        }
    };

    assert(std::find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), lambda) != a.end());
    assert(std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), lambda) != m.end());
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JnFiGpbKq8TbjF3s)

Have in mind that this approach won't work as expected if you decide to search through collection like `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`.