# How to understand C++ error, "no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::pair' and 'const int')"?

Tags: c++, operators

I am compiling the following code on codeblocks and I get the following error statement

> C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h|191|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::pair' and 'const int')

Also an error is displayed in the header file `predefined_ops.h`:

```
template<typename _Iterator>
    bool
    operator()(_Iterator __it)
    { return *__it == _M_value; }//error
    };
```

This is the code which I am compiling

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Soham
{
    int *a,n;
    map<int,int> m;
public:
    Soham(int x);
    void search1(int,int,int,int);
};
Soham::Soham(int x)
{
    n=x;
    a=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(abs(a[i]-a[j])<=1)
               {
                   search1(a[i],a[j],i,j);
               }
        }
    }
    map<int,int> ::iterator it1;
    for(it1=m.begin();it1!=m.end();it1++)
    {
        cout<<it1->first<<"-->"<<it1->second<<endl;
    }
}
void Soham::search1(int x,int y,int i1,int j1)
{
    if(m.empty())
    {
        m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(x,i1));
        m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(y,j1));
    }
    else
    {
       map<int,int>::iterator it,it1;
       it=find(m.begin(),m.end(),x);
       it1=find(m.begin(),m.end(),y);
       if(it!=m.end()|| it1!=m.end())
       {

           if (it!=m.end() && it->second!=i1)//chance of error 
              {
                    m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(it->first,i1));
              }


              if(it1!=m.end() && it1->second!=j1)//chance of error
            {
                    m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(it1->first,j1));
            }


       }
        //find failed to find element in the map how to show this particular condition
        else  //error
        {
            if(it!=m.end())
            {
                m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(x,i1));
            }
            if(it1!=m.end())
            {
                m.insert(std::pair<int,int>(y,j1));
            }

        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    Soham a(n);
    return 0;
}
```

As per the error statement i am doing an invalid comparison using the == operator, but i dont get get it 
this is where most probably the error occurs in the following conditions

```
 if (it!=m.end() && it->second!=i1)
 if(it1!=m.end() && it1->second!=j1)
```

In the second check I am checking the second element of the pair(it->second) which is of type int with an integer variable i1 then why is that the error occurs with the == operator. I may have understood the error in the wrong manner and accordingly explained my understanding, if that's not the case. What generates the error and how to rectify it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ STL: std::find with std::map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485829/c-stl-stdfind-with-stdmap)

Comment: If you follow the "chain" of error messages (they probably say "... instantiated from ...") the compiler should eventually tell you that the problem lies in the `find` lines. Navigating template error messages can be challenging at the best of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following lines and it will run

```
  //it=find(m.begin(),m.end(),x);
  it = m.find(x);
  //it1=find(m.begin(),m.end(),y);
  it1 = m.find(y);
```

Basically you have to use the `find` member function instead of the
`find` algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Partha for clarifying the issue:)